# Changing ImageView Resource Error

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am new to android and was starting out by making a basic Pokedex.  I've created two buttons on this activity with each button leading to the same new activity.  Everything works until I add in the change resource on the imageview.

I want to be able to change the image in the new activity depending on what button the user presses.  I have tried the button within the case statements and there is an error. So I moved it out to the MainActivity and also received an error.

```
package com.example.pokedex;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button buttonsquirtle;
Button buttonelectabuzz;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    buttonsquirtle=(Button)findViewById(R.id.moves);
    buttonelectabuzz=(Button)findViewById(R.id.moves2);
    buttonsquirtle.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonelectabuzz.setOnClickListener(this);

    ImageView imagemark = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imagemark.setImageResource(R.drawable.electabuzzicon);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.moves:

        Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this, Squirtle.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    case R.id.moves2:

        Intent j= new Intent(MainActivity.this, Squirtle.class);
        startActivity(j);   
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }       

}


}
```

Logcat Error is posted below:

```
03-10 11:05:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(32080): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-10 11:05:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(32080): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start      activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pokedex/com.example.pokedex.MainActivity}:     java.lang.NullPointerException
03-10 11:05:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
03-10 11:05:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
03-10 11:05:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
03-10 11:05:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
03-10 11:05:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-10 11:05:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-10 11:05:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
03-10 11:05:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-10 11:05:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-10 11:05:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
03-10 11:05:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
03-10 11:05:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-10 11:05:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(32080): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-10 11:05:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at com.example.pokedex.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
03-10 11:05:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
03-10 11:05:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
03-10 11:05:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
03-10 11:05:01.560: E/AndroidRuntime(32080):    ... 11 more
```

Here is the activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/moves"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:text="@string/squirtle_button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/moves2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/moves"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/electabuzz_button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the other xml file where the imageView1 is located:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Squirtle" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/moves"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="58dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:text="@string/moves" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/coverage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/moves"
    android:layout_below="@+id/moves"
    android:text="@string/weaknesses" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/evolution"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/coverage"
    android:layout_below="@+id/coverage"
    android:text="@string/evolution" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/evolution"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/moves"
    android:src="@drawable/squirtleicon"
    android:contentDescription="@string/squirtle_image_desc" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you sure `activity_main` layout contain `ImageView` with `imageView1` id?

Comment: post your `activity_main.xml`

Comment: My imageView1 is within a different xml. I'll post the xml

Comment: This is the reason for the NullPointerException - you must set the image resource from within your Squirtle activity, because the image doesn't exist in your MainActivity's layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would accomplish this by using an intent extra when launching the second activity:

```
// Launch the same activity for both buttons, but add a different value in the extras
case R.id.moves:
    Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this, Squirtle.class);
    i.putExtra("buttonPressed", "squirtle");
    startActivity(i);
    break;
case R.id.moves2:
    Intent j= new Intent(MainActivity.this, Squirtle.class);
    j.putExtra("buttonPressed", "electabuzz");
    startActivity(j);   
    break;
```

Then, in your second Activity's onCreate method:

```
// Get Intent used to launch activity
Intent launchingIntent = getIntent();
// Get extras
Bundle content = launchingIntent.getExtras();

// Set image based on which button was pressed
String buttonPressed = content.getString("buttonPressed");
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

if (buttonPressed.equals("squirtle")) {
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.squirtleicon);
} else if (buttonPressed.equals("electabuzz")) {
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.electabuzzicon);
}
```

This will mean that a different image is displayed in the second activity, based on which button the user pressed in the first activity.

Might also be a good idea to define the Strings using constants to prevent mis-type errors e.g. in MainActivity:

```
public final static String EXTRA_BUTTON_PRESSED = "buttonPressed";
public final static String BUTTON_SQUIRTLE = "squirtle";
public final static String BUTTON_ELECTABUZZ = "electabuzz";
```

And then reference this in the code instead:

```
i.putExtra(EXTRA_BUTTON_PRESSED, BUTTON_SQUIRTLE);
```

...

```
j.putExtra(EXTRA_BUTTON_PRESSED, BUTTON_ELECTABUZZ);
```

And in the second Activity:

```
String buttonPressed = content.getString(MainActivity.EXTRA_BUTTON_PRESSED);
```

...

```
if (buttonPressed == MainActivity.BUTTON_SQUIRTLE) { ...
```

The first way will work but is more susceptible to typos, amongst other things :)

Comment: Thank you.  This is what I wanted to accomplish, but I tried your code and it's always displaying squirtleicon.  Any suggestions?  Also, I tried adding Log.d to the two if statements and neither are activated when the buttons are clicked.

Comment: My mistake! replace the `if (buttonPressed == ...)` statements with `if (buttonPressed.equals(...))`, I've edited my answer. Basically, Strings should be compared with `equals()` rather than `==`.

Comment: No problem, happy developing :)